# How can I Create A Reticle in center view using RajawaliVR

Tags: android, sdk, virtual-reality, rajawalivr

How can I create a reticle using the Cardboard SDK for Android Studio and RajawaliVR 3D Renderer?

I search through out many websites and the Rajawali wiki on github to try and find a solution that would keep a 3D object in the center of the users view with perfect orientation.  I did stumble upon a link on the WIKI but it did not offer a solution that worked with RajawaliVR.
After some trial and error I came up with this solution

First create a 3D Object in the renderer

```
Sphere RETICLE = new Sphere(1, 50, 32);

    Material sphereMaterial = new Material();
    sphereMaterial.enableLighting(true);
    sphereMaterial.setDiffuseMethod(new DiffuseMethod.Lambert());
    RETICLE.setMaterial(sphereMaterial);

    try{
        sphereMaterial.addTexture(tExture);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException error){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "TEXTURE ERROR");
    }
```

Next you will need the following code placed in your renderer class

```
public void centerObject(Object3D obj){
    float[] newPosition4 = new float[4];
    float[] posVec4 = {0, 0, -3, 1.0f};
    float[] HeadViewMatrix_inv = new float[16];
    Matrix4 HeadViewMatrix4 = new Matrix4();
    HeadViewMatrix4.setAll(mHeadViewMatrix);
    HeadViewMatrix4 = HeadViewMatrix4.inverse();
    HeadViewMatrix4.toFloatArray(HeadViewMatrix_inv);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(newPosition4, 0, HeadViewMatrix_inv, 0, posVec4, 0);
    obj.setPosition(newPosition4[0], newPosition4[1], newPosition4[2]);

    obj.setLookAt(getCurrentCamera().getPosition());
}
```

You can then call the centerObject method from the onRender method or fram a handler.  (The on render method gets called everytime a new frame is drawn.)

```
@Override
public void onRender(long elapsedTime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(elapsedTime, deltaTime);
    if(RETICLE != null)centerObject(RETICLE);
}
```

Placing a null check before calling centerObject() is important because the scene may render before the object is created.

[Rajawali WIKI Link](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/1348)

The Rajawali WIKI link above offered some great clues but the issue has been closed.  I did comment there as well with my solution as to help provide a turn key solution for the next person facing the same problem.

I hope the helps some people.  Please post better, Improved or other solutions so others may benefit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution but I have one question. Does your gaze pointer of the left eye shake a lot, all the time, and the right one doesn't? See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021500/add-gaze-cursor-cardboard-using-opengl-or-rajawali3d-framework